# Stopping the agent: Reason = sig.kill in cloudstack kvm agent

Tags: kvm, libvirt, apache-cloudstack

I work with cloudstack4.9.2.0, have add a kvm host, the agent has started but it always crashed with log message:

```
[cloud.agent.Agent] (AgentShutdownThread:null) (logid:) Stopping the agent: Reason = sig.kill
```

and there is no more useful error message.
But when I use dmesg, I see these:

```
[18343.770338] libvirtd[5320]: segfault at 7fd34826c313 ip 00007fd34826c313 sp 00007fd343deacf0 error 14 in libnss_sss.so.2[7fd349a0f000+8000]

[18493.759889] libvirtd[10687]: segfault at 7f2d3ad17313 ip 00007f2d3ad17313 sp 00007f2d5016bcf0 error 14

[18642.749523] libvirtd[16073]: segfault at 7f098e654313 ip 00007f098e654313 sp 00007f09a4114cf0 error 14 in libnss_sss.so.2[7f098fdf7000+8000]

[18792.739096] libvirtd[21469]: segfault at 7f374ed17313 ip 00007f374ed17313 sp 00007f374e8dccf0 error 14

[18926.729704] libvirtd[26724]: segfault at 7fbaf62a9313 ip 00007fbaf62a9313 sp 00007fbaf5e6ecf0 error 14
```

does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like agent is being killed for some reason.
Can you check if Kvm host is able to access 8250 port of cloudstack server ?